# How to identify method subscribe has executed in Ionic 2 using Angularfire2

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to get data from Firebase in my Ionic2 project using Angular2. Following is the code.

```
  getNextItem(): string[] {

    this.af.database.object(`/user/${uid}/data`)
    .subscribe(value =>{
      this.item = value;
    });
    return this.item;
  }
```

In this case, my `item` is always empty as the `subscribe` method executes after my method is complete. I also can not return the `item` from inside the `subscribe` method.
So how will I be able to get the data and how to identify when `subscribe` method has executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you not have to create a new `Promise` maybe?

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
   this.af.database.object(`/user/${uid}/data`).subscribe(resolve => {
         this.item = resolve;
   });
 });
```

havent tried this code so not sure it works.

I generally write something like this

```
getDataByUser(fbPath: string, userId: string) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.af.database.list(`${fbPath}/${userId}/data`)
            .subscribe(res => resolve(res));
    })
}
```